# cmd batch need counter to assign unique number to list of files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, mp4

I am using Atomic Parsley in windows8 to set correct Atoms for my .mp4 TV shows. Right now I can correctly specify "common" tags such as Artist, TVShowName etc which are in fact the same for all files I am tagging. My problem is that in a batch file I am not able to tag the correct episode number to EACH file: "file001"should be episode1, "file002" -> episode2 and so forth.

Right now, I am using this to tag files:

```
for %%1 in (*.m4v *.mp4) do %AtomicParsley% "%%1" --stik "TV Show" --artist "%artist%" --title "%%~n1" --TVShowName "%TVShowName%" --TVSeasonNum %TVSeasonNum% --overWrite
```

What I need is some kind of counter that assign to this field `--TVEpisode` an increasing (in steps of lenght 1) and unique number. Obviously, I also need the preceding commands (or their equivalent) to work alongside the --TvEpisode counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET count=0
for %%e in (*.m4v *.mp4) do (
SET /a count+=1
%AtomicParsley% "%%e" --stik "TV Show" --artist "%artist%" --title "%%~ne" --TVShowName "%TVShowName%" --TVSeasonNum %TVSeasonNum% --overWrite --TVEpisode !count!
)
```

Assuming your utility will use the argument to `--TVEpisode` to assign the filename in the manner you wish.

Comment: thanks guys. For the sake of completeness, I was mistaken when I posted '--TVEpisode'. The actual switch is '--TVEpisodeNum'. Now it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

If your files are really named "file001", "file002", etc, you could grab the number from the filename instead of using a counter.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.mp4) do (
    set "filename=%%~na"
    set /a TVEpisode=1!filename:~-3!-1000
    %AtomicParsley% "%%a" --stik "TV Show" --artist "%artist%" --title "%%~n1" --TVShowName "%TVShowName%" --TVSeasonNum %TVSeasonNum% --overWrite --TVEpisode !TVEpisode!
)
```

The line `set /a TVEpisode=!filename:~-3!` is grabbing the last three characters of the filename and assigning them to %TVEpisode% as a number (thus dropping the leading zeros).  (It's actually prepending the three digits with a 1, then subtracting 1000 to get back the original number, because `set /a` treats the number as octal if it begins with a leading 0.)

Comment: This method fail if the number have leading zeros and digits greater than 7. The right expression is this: `set /a TVEpisode=1!filename:~-3!%%1000`

Comment: Thanks @Aacini!  I've been bit by that before.  Edited my answer.  (I made it `-1000` rather than `%%1000`--I'm guessing that was a typo of yours, or I'm not sure what you were getting at.)

Comment: `%` is the remainder (mod) operator. I customarily used it instead of subtract because it also works when the number of leading zeros is unknow: `set /A number=100!stringWith1to3Digits!%%1000`.